# Ruby method overloading

Tags: ruby, overloading

So I have to implement two different situations. One is a method that multiplies two numbers, and can also multiply more than 2 numbers.

I'm using the following:

```
def multiply(arr)
    arr.reduce(1, :*)
end
```

So far it works out fine if I unit test using an array input. Is there anyway to do this so my method can take in just two values, or an array, and return the relevant results? Is there also a way to implement this without even using an array input?

Comment: Consider using splat operator: `def multiply(*arr); ...; end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`splat`](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/) operator:

```
def multiply(*arr)
  arr.reduce(1, :*)
end

multiply(2, 3, 4, 5)
# => 120
```

If you want to *also* want to support input as an array, you can use `flatten` on `arr`:

```
def multiply(*arr)
  arr.flatten.reduce(1, :*)
end

multiply([2, 3, 4, 5])
# => 120 
multiply(10, 3, 5)
# => 150 
multiply(10, 3)
# => 30
```